# How to send a request to my add in when a user changes the date of a meeting inside outlook (without opening the add-in)?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm building an Outlook Add-in where the user can book a meeting directly from outlook. The add in is basically a shortcut to the website we usually use, but instead we take the data from the outlook meeting (Date, title, etc..). The problem is that once the user has created a meeting and it has been saved in our database (and they close the add-in), the add-in can't detect if they change the meeting date, and therefore it doesn't get updated in the database.

Shortly put: Is there any way that my add-in can communicate with outlook and fire a function without being opened?

Comment: To clarify, are you writing a Outlook web addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) or a COM addin?  For web addins, the addin needs to be open to run.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT It is an Outlook Web addin

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Would there be a way for the user to let the web add-in always run in the background? And possibly also start as soon as outlook is opened. Otherwise, would it be possible to achieve this with a COM addin? Thanks

Comment: A addin that is always running in the background cannot be done with web addins. Have you looked into using graph APIs from your backend to get change notifications?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Can I set up a webhook from my add-In that points to my backend? @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT